# Windows Store Apps - Add Project Reference Warning

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting the following warning when attempting to add a reference to my Windows Store App project:

> Adding reference to 'LegacyLibrary' is not recommended because it is
>   not compatible with Windows Store Apps.
>
> Would you like to add this reference?

What is it warning me about? Why isn't it compatible? Can you call legacy code from a Windows Store App project?

After building I get the following warning:

> warning MSB8019: This build is consuming a component
>   "LegacyLibrary\Output\Debug x64\LegacyLibrary.lib" that is not
>   packaged because the component is not coming from a Windows Store app
>   project

Annoyingly, there are no search results for MSB8019...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each project you want to reference from your Windows Store App, you need to go the `Properties | General` and then change `Windows App Store Support` to `Yes`. This will allow the project to be referenced by your Windows Store App project. If you want to use the new WindowsRT API from within these legacy apps, you will need to go to `Properties | C/C++ | General` and change `Consume Windows Runtime Extension` to `Yes (/ZW)`.